# Is there a way to update a Postgresql view via a “catch-all” where condition?

Tags: postgresql, view, rules

I am currently trying to work out views with rules. In my case, I have a complex view with a joins done on two tables. In this case, I want to update / delete from the table with a where condition. Reading from the docs, this is possible by using rules.
The problem with using rules is that we have to also specify a different where in each rule. Is it possible to have a sort of catch all rule to apply whatever where clause we want?

For example, we can have a view on a join of two tables with multiple columns. We then want to propagate any updates / deletes on that view with any where clause, is this possible without creating a rule for every possibly combination?

EDIT: Here's an image of what I mean. Is there a way to have a generic / blanket update to allow any where condition to the view?

Fiddle Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/_P8IjlI5

Comment: **DO NOT use rules** you will regret it. Use `INSTEAD OF` triggers instead per [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: Per [CREATE VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html): *A more complex view that does not satisfy all these conditions is read-only by default: the system will not allow an insert, update, or delete on the view. You can get the effect of an updatable view by creating INSTEAD OF triggers on the view, which must convert attempted inserts, etc. on the view into appropriate actions on other tables. For more information see CREATE TRIGGER. Another possibility is to create rules (see CREATE RULE), but in practice triggers are easier to understand and use correctly.*

Comment: Do you have an example of what I want to do using triggers? I read through the documentation, but didn’t see anything specific to my case.

Comment: 1) Since you have not actually any specifics about your case it is not really possible to say. Short version is the trigger will call a function that does the actual work 2) Search on *postgresql instead of trigger updatable views* for examples

Comment: If you want an example of an *Instead of* trigger then post an example of your requirement. Include in it table and view (with join) definitions (ddl), a few rows of test data in each table, and  DML statement(2) with the expected results. Post all ad formatted text - **no images** - or better yet a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: Hey, I attached a picture to my original post using fiddle or here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrLyV.png if you could take a look! Thanks!

Comment: @Belayer specifically requested **no images**, please comply with that.

Comment: Why are  you even creating a view? You are only updating the columns in table1.

Answer (score 0):

What you show in the fiddle can be done without a view:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  table1_id INTEGER REFERENCES table1(id),
  column3 BOOLEAN
);

-- Insert some data into the tables
INSERT INTO table1 (id, column1, column2)
VALUES (1, 'value1', 'value2');

INSERT INTO table2 (id, table1_id, column3)
VALUES (1, 1, false);

-- Data will not be there
INSERT INTO table1 (id, column1, column2)
VALUES (2, 'value1', 'value2');
INSERT INTO table2 (id, table1_id, column3)
VALUES (2, 2, true);

UPDATE
    table1
SET
    (column1, column2) = ('new','new2')
WHERE
    column1 = 'value1'
    AND id = (
        SELECT
            t1.id
        FROM
            table1 t1
            JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
                AND t2.column3 != TRUE);

select * from table1;
 id | column1 | column2 
----+---------+---------
  2 | value1  | value2
  1 | new     | new2
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I am mainly trying to find a way to not have to do the joins every time. I know it can be done without a view, but the view makes it so I don’t have to do the joins and filter by the where every time.

Comment: A view has conditions set by the query that creates it. You cannot change that on the fly, so either 1) You create a generic view with no `WHERE` and add the `WHERE` conditions when you do the query against it 2)  You create a view with `WHERE` conditions for every possible combination 3) You do as I show above. 1) and 2) impose overhead of the view and the triggers, so as the data set gets bigger that could become an issue.